# Troubleshooting Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Wifi Problems

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, 20.04

I have an uncommon hardware configuration.  I'm running an AMD APU r7 3700U Vega 10. Problem-solving is keeping me busy, but I'm still a beginner.  I'm currently tethered to my phone and when I boot Ubuntu it's a dice roll whether the wifi adapter is recognized or not (as well as whether I have audio?)

https://www.newegg.com/icicle-silver-asus-zenbook-um433da-nh74-mainstream/p/N82E16834235285

I've identified my wireless card as an Intel 8265/8275
I installed Mainline to update the kernel to 5.8 - no dice so far.

I'm trying to follow these instructions:

> https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-wi-fi-not-working-ubuntu/

> https://www.intel.com.au/content/www/au/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless.html

I'm trying to figure out what the module is but I have no idea?

https://pastebin.com/JucndMbp (couldn't figure out how to format the terminal output).

Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265       4.6+

iwlwifi-8265-ucode-22.361476.0.tgz - I think this is what I'm looking for?

Edit:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:8110]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983 [144d:a808]
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Here's a wireless diagnostic that I found googling around:

https://termbin.com/zd1b (this is my system).

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=285630 - Little hesitant to try any of this since I have an Asus and these seem to be for Lenovo?

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[sudo] password for wist: 
[    1.969622] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.296862] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -110
```

Comment: This device should work without any problems unless it is blocked by rfkill. Instead of installing mainline kernels that can cause some more trouble, check `rfkill` and `dmesg`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: I edited in the output Pilot6.  

The dmesg output is enormous as well, do you want that too?

Comment: Run `dmesg | grep iwl`. That will be short. Also is it a dual boot with Windows?

Comment: And try to boot with an Ubuntu kernel, not a mainline.

Comment: So we see that te module can't load. If it is a dual boot, disable Windows Fast Start.

Comment: Yeah, it's a dual-boot with Windows.  I'm on 5.4.0-48-generic
via the recovery menu.  Still isn't detecting a wifi adapter.

Comment: So disable Windows Fast Start feature and all will work. Windows doesn't shut down properly.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That did it on both 5.4 and 5.8.  I've got audio back as well which is fantastic.  I suppose the days when it was working over the past week were days where the system fully shut down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable Windows Fast Start feature and drivers should work.